# Generating Dacpac file using MSbuild in Azure Devops for CI-CD is slow

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops, msbuild, continuous-integration

I am trying to generate pipeline build/dacpac file for 1000 stored Procedures of SQL server 2008 using MSBBuild in Azure Devops for CI-CD purpose. I am using Azure git repo and self hosted Agent to generate build. But the problem is that it is taking 36 minutes to generate the build. This is way too much slow!!!! I tried with Azure pipeline agent as well but that is even worse.

How to generate pipeline build faster for SQL sever objects more than thousand ? Am I making any mistake ?

Comment: This issue may be due to some errors that do not terminate the build and do not affect the results of the build. How long will it take to compile the solution locally with the local `MSbuild` command? Could you provide the debug log? (Debug logs can be seen by setting variable `System.debug` with value `true`) It is important to know where the program is spending the most time and whether there are error messgaes or warning messages.

Comment: Hi Shah, is there any update for this issue?

Comment: Hi Jane, Sorry for the late reply. I try to build solution locally in VS2019 but it did not get complete even after around 3 hours and then I cancelled the build. I am not much aware about system variables. But It was stuck at "Building the project model and resolving object interdependencies..." My solution has around 9k SPs and 2k Tables and few other objects like UDFs and Views. My observation is that as the SP count increases, the time for the build is getting increasing significantly. There are no errors in it but yes there are plenty of warning as the database is being used in ssms.